# How to use snap.svg draw the loading icon

Tags: svg, loading, snap.svg, svg-animate

How to use snap.svg draw the loading as this https://jxnblk.github.io/loading/,

I think that may use the method `Snap.load`, but I want it centered in the container.

I try to use `pager.group` to wrap it, but they are all smaller than the original ones.

I alse try to use css to control their styles!

demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/icai/w2N47/

Comment: Maybe if you put the code on a jsfiddle you have it would help.

Comment: @Ian I had updated the link

Comment: That looks fine in the fiddle, so are you just wanting to reposition or scale it or what ?

Comment: @Ian I know that use translate to reposition it. but have another question why the pattern image fill circle is blank? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123134/svg-patttern-image-fill-circle-is-blank-in-server-test-but-not-in-localfile-pa